# WSO2 EMM - What is purpose iOS Agent?

Tags: wso2, wso2-iot

I have successfully installed & configured WSO2 EMM. I am trying to customize the flow of MDM profile installation.

Is it requires to have iOS agent to be installed on a device in order to install MDM profile?

If it is required for WSO2 EMM, how can we avoid it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IOS Agent is installed on a device to retrieve the GEO related data. you can skip the installation of the IOS agent and continue to the profile installation.